# Displaying 30 Instagram Images of certain tag of certain userID

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, instagram

I have an Instagram API call that requests images tagged with CrookedSpaces, when those images return I am filtering the data making sure that only images from a certain user (using their userID), the code follows:

```
$(function() {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    cache: false,
    url: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/crookedspaces/media/recent/?count=100&access_token=TOKEN",
    success: function(data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < 31; i++) {
            var igUID = data.data[i].user.id;
            if(igUID === "USER ID") {
                $(".instagram").append("\
                    <div class='instagram-feed'>\
                        <img class='instagram-image' src='" + data.data[i].images.standard_resolution.url +"' width='325px' alt='" + data.data[i].user.id + " " + igUID + "' onMouseOver=\"toggle_visibility('igImageHover" + i + "');\"/>\
                            <div class='igHover' id='igImageHover" + i + "' onMouseOut=\"toggle_visibility('igImageHover" + i + "');\">\
                            <div class='igHover2'>\
                                SMALL TEST!\
                            </div />\
                            </div>\
                    </div>\
                ");
            } else {
                    console.log("Else portion of code ran " + elseCount + " time(s).");
                    ++elseCount;
                }
        }                
    }
});
});
```

However, I am only able to display 27 images because there are 4 images not posted by that specific userID. Is there some way to force the for loop to not increment? Or to subtract 1 from i without sending the code into an infinite loop?

Here is the JSFiddle -- http://jsfiddle.net/UQcZP/

Comment: Could you post a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.demo) that we could work with?

Comment: maybe use the size of the returned array as your for condition and increment a counter when the user id matches, then break out of the loop when you have the desired number of images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a while loop:

```
var i = 0;
var used=0;
while (used<31)
{
  if (i < data.data.length){
     // .. Do your work here
     // only increment used when you actually get a match
  }
  else
  {
     // Here we are past the end of the data and did not reach the 30 items, 
     // so just set the number of items to 31 to exit the loop.
     used = 31; 
  }
  i++;    
}​
```

Comment: This answer worked perfectly, however I Went a different route with the coding.

Figured I could at least vote / close this question.