# Filter instagram api results by tag AND username

Tags: jquery, json, api, instagram

I'd like to create an application that pulls images from a certain tag, but only from a certain username.  For example:  I'd like #skullcandysnow images to appear, but only the ones from the 'skullcandy' account name.

Here is how I'm pulling the tag:

```
 $(function() {

 $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        cache: false,
        url: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/skullcandysnow/media/recent?client_id=d1685ded02da4c5eb2b08632f1256119&access_token=fce470c159274e2b9482976f93fd3435",
        success: function(data) {



            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

        $(".SC-IG").append("<img class='SC-instagram-image' src='" + data.data[i].images.low_resolution.url +"' /><div class='counts'><img src='images/skullcandyad_04.jpg'><h3 class='ig-likescount'>" + data.data[i].likes.count +"</h3><h3 class='ig-commentscount'>" + data.data[i].comments.count +"</h3></div> ");   


        }
       }

    });
});
```

You can view what I'm working on here:  http://yobeat.com/zz_testing/yobeatinstagramwidget_v3.html

Thanks!

Comment: from the looks of it, because it's a RESTful API, I don't see any easy way of doing it

Comment: hmm. can you suggest a better way of going about it?

Comment: I would get all the images from the user, then check each image for the tag

Comment: please post you answer with code - and also accept it. It can be helpful for other users with )

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12375828/displaying-30-instagram-images-of-certain-tag-of-certain-userid?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Looking through the code provided by the user on his 'figured it out' website, the solution was as follow:

```
imgLimit = 1000;
// Grab all TAGS of choice
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    cache: false,
    url: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/TAG_OF_CHOICE/media/recent?client_id=CLIENT_ID&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN",
    success: function(data) { 
    // Loop through the data and only add the images that match a certain user ID
        for (var i = 0; i < imgLimit; i++) {
            var usertag = data.data[i].user.id;
            if (usertag === "USER_ID_OF_CHOICE") {
                // Add image to page
                addImage(data.data[i]);
            }
       }
    }
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately not a very efficient or practical solution, as it requires iterating over all images returned by the feed (how many is that?) and selecting only those posted by the user. For popular tags, the filter may not match any of the user's own photos.

Comment: I didn't say it was the best, just posted what the user had - Please provide a better way of doing it, if you have it.

Comment: Short of pre-processing the feed server-side, there aren't too many options here. Probably better to rethink the product and try to understand if you really need to filter by tag *and* user.